# Price formatter for range of variation products

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to write a price formatter to display the lowest and highest price of a collection of product variations? My reason for thinking it might not work is the scope of the product variation vs. it's "parent" product display.

If not, is there some way to build a view that will query to max ( and another for the min ) price of a collection of variations under one product display?

**For Example:**

I have a product display with 4 variations. Each variation has a different size lets say, and therefore each variation has a different price. I'm looking for a way for my product display to show the price of the cheapest variation and the highest priced variation as a range. As opposed to the first variation price that is shown now

Answer (score 0):

[Commerce Pricing Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes)

> This module provides some enhancements to the Commerce Product Option
>   and Commerce Product Attributes handling by applying pricing rules to
>   custom product attributes. So, you can add attributes to products that
>   affect the final product price.

- Dynamic price calculation based on selected operators.
- Cart combination based on product attributes.
- Support for multi currency.
- Multilingual attributes.
- Different attributes and settings per product.
- Price adjustments either per item or per order.
- Rules integration.
- Easy UI for editing and reordering attributes